# Cytoscape js prevents onChange function for input tags

Tags: javascript, onchange, cytoscape.js

I have a React Container that renders a cytoscape instance. In the container I also have a modal component which contains a slider component which contains an input tag.

The problem is that this input tag has an onChange function that never gets called.

Is there a way to stop cytoscape from preventing the listeners on input tags?

I have tried modifying the z-index of the modal component so that it is above cytoscape but it still didn't work. I have also tried turning of eventlisteners to cytoscape: For example:

```
props.cy.removeAllListeners();
props.cy.userZoomingEnabled(false);
props.cy.userPanningEnabled(false);
props.cy.boxSelectionEnabled(false);
props.cy.panningEnabled(false);
props.cy.zoomingEnabled(false);
props.cy.autoungrabify(true);
props.cy.autounselectify(true);
```

I know that if I have an onclick event handler within an anchor tag it works.

Also if I manually move the position of the modal(using the console) so that it is not overtop the cytoscape instance it works fine.

The following is the simplified parent component

```
class GraphContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      showSettings: false,
    };
    this.cy = React.createRef();
    this.toggleSettings = this.toggleSettings.bind(this);
    this.setupCytoscape = this.setupCytoscape.bind(this);
    // and a bunch of other bindings
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    const container = ReactDOM.findDOMNode(this);
    this.cy = new cytoscape(
      {
        container, // container to render in
        style: stylesheet,
      },
    );

    this.setupCytoscape();
    this.loadData();
  }

// Function to hold all cy event listeners.
  setupCytoscape() {
    this.cy.on('dragfree', 'node', event => this.props.UpdateNodePosition(event.target));
    // and many more listeners
    };

  toggleSettings() {
    this.setState({ showSettings: !this.state.showSettings });
  }

render() {
    return (
      <div>
        {this.state.showSettings &&
        <GraphSettingsModal
          showSettings={this.state.showSettings}
          toggleSettings={this.toggleSettings}
          cy={this.cy}
          setupCy={this.setupCytoscape}
        />
        }
        <div className="ng-settings" onClick={e => this.toggleSettings(e)} >SETTINGS</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

and this is the child component:

```
const GraphSettingsModal = (props) => {
  // Stateless version of componentDidMount().
  useEffect(() => {
    // remove all listeners, zooming and panning from parent cytoscape component.
    props.cy.removeAllListeners();
    props.cy.userZoomingEnabled(false);
    props.cy.userPanningEnabled(false);
    props.cy.boxSelectionEnabled(false);
    props.cy.panningEnabled(false);
    props.cy.zoomingEnabled(false);
    props.cy.autoungrabify(true);
    props.cy.autounselectify(true);
    // Put all listeners back and resume panning and zooming for parent cytoscape component.
    // Stateless version of componentWillUnmount().
    return () => {
      props.setupCy();
      props.cy.userZoomingEnabled(true);
      props.cy.userPanningEnabled(true);
      props.cy.boxSelectionEnabled(true);
      props.cy.panningEnabled(true);
      props.cy.zoomingEnabled(true);
      props.cy.autoungrabify(false);
      props.cy.autounselectify(false);
    };
  });

  return (
    <Modal
      className="ng-modal"
      toggle={props.toggleSettings}
      width={700}
      height={300}
      visible={props.showSettings}
    >
      <input
        id="test-slide"
        value={5}
        onChange={(e) => { console.log('onChange works'); }}
      />
    </Modal>
  );
};

I'm hoping to find a way to allow tags to exist on top of the cytoscape component and still properly listen to events.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your modal div seems to be within the graph div rather than on top of it.

Comment: But would not changing the z-index effectively move it to the top?

Comment: No. Being the topmost child div within the div of interest is not the same as being on top of the div.

Comment: So to confirm, you are saying the only way possible is to have the GraphSettingsModal exist within the parent div instead of the graph div?